# Удалить систему управления версиями в VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git

Возможно удалить систему управления версиями из решения в Visual Studio 2019 с помощью интерфейса?

Comment: Система управления версиями не относится ни к Visual Studio, ни к решению.

Comment: В папке решения находите скрытый каталог `.git` и несколько раз перекрестившись удаляете его, и все, нет больше контроля версий в решении.